# SQL Create Table Error

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Thanks for all the help everyone provides.

I am trying to run my DDL statements and I am getting a weird error. If I copy and paste the ddl it works, but when I try to run it from a *.sql file, it gives an error. Here it is:

```
mysql> source createtable.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREAT
E TABLE stars
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(50) NOT ' at line 12
```

I don't know if this makes a difference or not, but it is the second table def in my ddl script.

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
Here is the starting of the DDL. It gives me an error on the second table.

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
year int NOT NULL,
director varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
banner_url varchar(200) default '',
trailer_url varchar(200) default '', 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE stars
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
dob date,
photo_url varchar(200) default '',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Post the content of createtable.sql please

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a `NULL` next to that `NOT` (`NOT NULL`) on your line 12?

Comment: No I think that is just where the error message cut off. Thanks though

Comment: Maybe you are missing a semicolon at the end of each table definition?

Comment: Are you running the two sets of sql on the same sql servers/instances? - I assume it works in development, but not when you try to release it?

Comment: Could there possibly be an error where I use id again? I know its in  a different table but thats the only thing I can think off.

Comment: @JonEgerton It works when I type the create tables in individually but when I type them together or from a source then it throws the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to separate your statements with semicolons:

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
year int NOT NULL,
director varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
banner_url varchar(200) default '',
trailer_url varchar(200) default '', 
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE stars
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
last_name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
dob date,
photo_url varchar(200) default '',
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: LOL wow I feel stupid. Thanks. I learned sql a while back and I am just getting back into using it.